# Windows Vista email (.eml) files - how to open in thunderbird

Tags: email

I am new to Linux/Ubuntu, just 3 days. I installed it when windows Vista crashed due to a very bad virus. Ubuntu is working very well but I would like to know how to put my emails from Windows Mail backups in a format I can use in Thunderbird. While in Windows I was not able to export them in an "importable" format (Vcard or txt) but I can read them in Ubuntu by double clicking on them. The problem is to know the author, date, subject etc. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird has an [import/export](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools/) add-on for this.